# Return the first word in a list contained in each row of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of string, How do I find the first string of that list contained in each row of a dataframe column and add it ito a new column?

This is the list:

```
Place = ['Abule-Egba', 'Agege', 'Alapere', 'Alimosho', 
         'Ajah', 'Amuwo-Odofin', 'Apapa', 'Bariga', 'Badagry', 
         'Epe', 'Ejigbo', 'Gbagada', 'Iddo-Island', 'Idimu', 'Igando', 
         'Ijora', 'Ikeja', 'isherri','Lekki', 'Ojo']
```

and the dataframe column with 9784 rows  Address:

```
0       Eleranigbe Eleranigbe Eleranigbe Ibeju Lekki L...
1             Opebi street opebi street Opebi Ikeja Lagos
2                          VI Lagos VI Extension VI Lagos
3               off afrika lane Lekki Phase 1 Lekki Lagos
4           NEAR IGANDO B/STOP Igando Ikotun Igando Lagos
5       Tijani Salako off Bode Shodiya street Bucknor ...
6       Fatade street, off Isheri/ Ijegun Rd, Kuduyeib...
7       Shodimu street by K& S B/stop, Abaranje Abaran...
8                 Banana island Banana Island Ikoyi Lagos
9               Oral Estate Oral Estate Ikota Lekki Lagos
10                         Ajah Ajah Sangotedo Ajah Lagos
11                Lekki Phase 1 Lekki Phase 1 Lekki Lagos
12       Jakande Pinnock Beach estate Jakande Lekki Lagos
13      opic estate isheri lagos opic Isheri North Ojo...
14                          ELEKO Eleko Ibeju Lekki Lagos
15                            chevron Chevron Lekki Lagos
```

Im  trying to create a new column like so:

```
                         1                                           2
0       Eleranigbe Eleranigbe Eleranigbe Ibeju Lekki L...          Lekki
1             Opebi street opebi street Opebi Ikeja Lagos          Ikeja
2                          VI Lagos VI Extension VI Lagos            VI
3               off afrika lane Lekki Phase 1 Lekki Lagos          Lekki
4           NEAR IGANDO B/STOP Igando Ikotun Igando Lagos          Igando
5       Tijani Salako off Bode Shodiya street Bucknor ...          Ikoyi
6       Fatade street, off Isheri/ Ijegun Rd, Kuduyeib...          Isheri
```

Heres the code i have but i get an error; **ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index**

```
s['where'] =''
de = []
for i in s['Address]:
    for j in Place:
        if j in i:
            de.append(j)

            break;
```

I think my code is wrong but i can for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: If there are no matches...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should be possible using `df.str.extract`:

```
df['Places'] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(Place) + ')', expand=False)
df.head()
                                                   1  Places
0  Eleranigbe Eleranigbe Eleranigbe Ibeju Lekki L...   Lekki
1        Opebi street opebi street Opebi Ikeja Lagos   Ikeja
2                     VI Lagos VI Extension VI Lagos     NaN
3          off afrika lane Lekki Phase 1 Lekki Lagos   Lekki
4      NEAR IGANDO B/STOP Igando Ikotun Igando Lagos  Igando
```